# Magento 2 product detail page detail tab vertical

Tags: magento2, product-view, tabs

I want to make product detail tab vertical instead of horizontal.

[image]

Comment: I think you can do it with CSS

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This requirement can be done by css.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following css should give you a good starting point, you will need to change paddings/borders also to make it pretty though.

```css
.catalog-product-view .product.data.items > .item.title { float: none; }
.catalog-product-view .product.data.items > .item.content { float: none; margin-left: 0; }
```

Comment: Is it possible to close all tabs by default? @siux

Comment: @RamalakshmiT it should be possible, i don't have a solution at hand though. the simplest, but dirty answer would be to add some js that closes the first tab with a fake click.